# Poll messages from kafka topic every X minutes

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I wanted to know that in my Kafka Streams application or Spring-Kafka;

Is there a way where I can read my messages from a topic in some time interval.

Read 1000 records per 5 minutes let's say.

Read 1000 records from a topic, wait 5 min again and consume 1000 messages again.

I have read the .poll() documentation but it does not do what I actually want. It says

```
 The configuration poll.ms is the maximum "blocking time" within poll() if no data avaliable.
```

Think like a slow notification processing. Can I handle this with consumer, producer api or using kafka streams ?

Thanks !

Comment: That does not seem to be a common use case for a streaming environment. However what you possibly could do is using the kafka streams windowing features, the tumbling time window to be exact. I am not sure, as I did not use is so far but is sounds like something you could consider.  https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#windowing-tumbling

Comment: I guess the question is, why do you want to do this? What is the problem you try to solve and why is `poll.ms` and `max.poll.records` not sufficient? Also, what happens if more input data is written upstream? For this case you would fall back and start to lag.

Comment: I am not sure did I understand poll.ms configuration correctly. When I configure poll.ms for 5 minutes my service starts to read messages after 5 minutes but it never stops and continipusly reads messages from topic :/